# display content if no toggle is active?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an icon bar with a simple script to hide/show the content. If a tab is active the and the user clicks it again it will disappear and display nothing below the icon bar. Is there a way to have content displayed when no icons are active?

HTML and JS:

```
<div class="container text-center">
    <div class="icon-bar">
        <a href="#box" class="toggle-state"><i class="fa fa-line-chart"></i></a>
        <a href="#box2"><i class="fa fa-heartbeat"></i></a>
        <a href="#box3"><i class="fa fa-diamond"></i></a>
        <a href="#box4"><i class="fa fa-exchange"></i></a>
        <a href="#box5"><i class="fa fa-newspaper-o"></i></a>
    <script>
    $("a").click(function(){
        var myelement = $(this).attr("href")
        $(myelement).slideToggle(1);
        $(".toggle:visible").not(myelement).hide();
    });
    </script>
    </div>
</div>
```

example of what one of the `<div>`'s looks like.

```
<div id="box2" class="toggle" style="display: none;">
    <p>content here</p>
</div>
```

Comment: It sounds like you're looking for `if ($(element).is(":visible"))`.

Comment: @ObsidianAge It sounds like you're an angel! happy weekend. cheers from over the pond.